# LDAP + Spring: как авторизоваться правильно?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

В Spring есть реализация авторизация по LDAP. В нашем конкретном случае, это происходит через `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

Выглядит это так:

```
private Authentication authenticate(String username, String password, HelpDescUser userDetails) {
    String url = "ldap://" + ldapHost + ":" + port + "/";
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ldapProvider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url, rootDn);
    String filterWithName = String.format(filter, username);
    ldapProvider.setSearchFilter(filterWithName);
    ldapProvider.setContextEnvironmentProperties(createProperties(username, password));
    ldapProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

    Authentication authenticate;
    try {
        authenticate = ldapProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Пользователь не авторизован (сервер LDAP не подтвердил авторизацию).");
    }
    if (Objects.nonNull(authenticate) && authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Пользователь не авторизован (сервер LDAP не подтвердил авторизацию).");
    }
}

private Map<String, Object> createProperties(String username, String password) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    return properties;
}
```

Есть проблема.

Как я понимаю схему авторизации, если мы хотим авторизоваться под каким-нибудь юзером, нам необходимо иметь также технический аккаунт. Мы биндимся под техническим аккаунтом, потом забрасываем на авторизацию логин и пароль юзера и получаем ответ - авторизован он или нет. Но в данной схеме биндинг происходит под тем же юзером, что и пытается авторизоваться, что неправильно.

Подскажите, есть ли готовое решение по авторизации через биндинг технического аккаунта через `Spring ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`?